# SQL query not executing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a php file that doesn't work but doesn't return any errors. The only part that seems to be not functional is preparing and executing the statement. Here is the code for preparing/executing:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':proname', $proname);
$stmt->bindValue(':category', $cat);
$stmt->bindValue(':maker', $maker);
$stmt->bindValue(':imgext', $picExt);
$stmt->bindValue(':creator', $user);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here is the query:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO product(proname, category, maker, imgext, creator) VALUES(:pronamename, :category, :maker, :imgext, :creator);';
```

Why isn't it working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you enable errors through PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Can you try running the raw query on the database. It looks good to me from php side.

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has `:pronamename` but you're trying to bind a value to `:proname`

You just need to change one to match the other.

Comment: Thank you for helping. It worked and I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @simonb, also look into the error handling link I posted.  PDO is silent by default.  Enabling error handling (like exceptions for instance) would probably have saved you the time of coming here.